# How can I avoid force cast type in IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

Problem description:

IDEA 2019.3

[image: problem img]

```
    public Rmap reduce(BinaryOperator<Rmap> accumulator) {
        return new Rec(ds.reduce((r1, r2) -> {
            Rmap rr = accumulator.apply(new Rec(r1), new Rec(r2));
            return rec(rr).row();
        }));
    }
```

I know forced cast type can solved the problem,but I don't want to it.

Because,If i push it to git,
It will be inconsistent with colleagues who use eclipse.
This is normal on eclipse.

The proble not affect the operation but looks uncomfortable,How can I avoid force cast type in IDEA?

Comment: It seems not an IDEA issue, but compiller. Code will not wirk

Comment: Show us more code, so we can help you find out why

Comment: at the bottom right of you application window you should see an icon of an "inspector" (a guy with a hat). You can click on it and configure what kind of code inspection you like. Try filtering for "errors" only and search for this "inspection hint". If you don't want it to show in red, set it to "warning" only or just remove the inspection.

Comment: Please paste code and error messages into your question as formatted text.

Comment: If the cast makes the code more readable Then I would go with the cast. Perhaps ask a couple of the other devs on the team what they think and go with the majority.  On the other hand the error message looks like a compiler issue to me so you may be forced to cast.

Comment: @GameDroids sorry,I not fount it,can you give screenshots in answer

Comment: @Gavin That makes sense.But the leadership felt that the force cast was a bit redundant, which was a matter of code style

Comment: in IntelliJ go to `preferences > Editor > Inspections`. Then you might want to have a look at the `Java` node first. However I didn't find what you are looking for, but I guess you know better where to look for it.

Comment: @Pooky fair enough. Though I would say sometimes the redundancy is worth the additional readability, but at the end of the day you do have to get it through review. 

Comment: Is the issue reproduced for you with the latest build (2020.1.1, https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download)? Please provide the dependencies for the code so that it can be reproduced. Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho yes,I try to use 2020.1.1,same problem

Comment: Can you please file an issue at the YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/) providing the code with the dependencies (it can be done privately) so that it can be reproduced. Thanks